# react-native-snap-carousel, snapToItem does not move the slider to a specific position when list length is more than 15 items

Tags: react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

There is an image slider that contains more than 200 images there is a circular slider from which we slide that image slider. so we need to call the snapToItem method to move the carousel in a specific position. but snapToItem does not move the carousel to a specific position.

If the slider has only 10 or 15 images then it works perfectly but if we have more than 15 images **snapToItem** method doesn't work properly.

```
 <Carousel
          ref={carouselRef}
          data={data}
          renderItem={renderCarouselItem}
          sliderWidth={width}
          itemWidth={ITEM_WIDTH}
          contentContainerCustomStyle={STYLES.paddingBottom10}
          lockScrollWhileSnapping
          onSnapToItem={index => setFocusedSliderIndex(index)}
          containerCustomStyle={{
            marginTop: heightToDp(10),
          }}
          enableMomentum
          // scrollInterpolator={scrollInterpolator}
          // slideInterpolatedStyle={animatedStyles}
        />
```

```
  // we call the onUpdate function to move the slider using ciruclar-slider.
  const onUpdate = () => {
    // where we pass newIndex is dyanamic
    if (carouselRef && carouselRef.current) {
        carouselRef.current.snapToItem(newIndex);
    }
  };
```

[image]

```
Platform:- iOS/android (both)
react-native: 0.66.4,
react-native-snap-carousel: 3.9.1
```